# How to rotate a QGraphicsPixmap around a point according to mouseMoveEvent?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem

I want rotate a QGraphicsPixmapItem around a point according to mouse position.

So i tried this:

```
void Game::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e){
  setMouseTracking(true);
QPoint midPos((sceneRect().width() / 2), 0), currPos;

currPos = QPoint(mapToScene(e->pos()).x(), mapToScene(e->pos()).y());


QPoint itemPos((midPos.x() - cannon->scenePos().x()), (midPos.y() - cannon->scenePos().y()));

double angle = atan2(currPos.y(), midPos.x()) - atan2(midPos.y(), currPos.x());
cannon->setTransformOriginPoint(itemPos);
cannon->setRotation(angle); }
```

But the pixmap moves a few of pixels.

I want a result like this:
[image]

Comment: atan2 returns radians. setRotation takes degrees.

Comment: Thank you, now the qgraphicitem is moving a lot more than before, but seems like that the TransformOriginPoint is wrong...

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, if it is pressed at a point inside the item then I assume that the center of rotation is that point, is that correct? If so, then what is the angle of rotation? If not, what is the center of rotation and what is the angle? Also, what happens if the item is clicked outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the mixup of degrees and radians that @rafix07 pointed out there is a bug in the angle calculation. You basically need the angle of the line from `midPos` to `currPos` which you calculate by

```
double angle = atan2(currPos.y() - midPos.y(), currPos.x() - midPos.x());
```

Additionally the calculation of the transformation origin assumes the wrong coordinate system. The origin must be given in the coordinate system of the item in question (see [QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setTransformOriginPoint)), not in scene coordinates. Since you want to rotate around the center of that item it would just be:

```
QPointF itemPos(cannon->boundingRect().center());
```

Then there is the question whether `midPos` is actually the point highlighted in your image in the middle of the canon. The y-coordinate is set to 0 which would normally be the edge of the screen, but your coordinate system may be different.
I would assume the `itemPos` calculated above is just the right point, you only need to map it to scene coordinates (`cannon->mapToScene(itemPos)`).

Lastly I would strongly advise against rounding scene coordinates (which are `double`s) to `int`s as it is done in the code by forcing it to `QPoint`s instead of `QPointF`s. Just use `QPointF` whenever you are dealing with scene coordinates.